# Regex - split by "_" and exclude file extension

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split the following string `AAA_BBB_CCC.extension` by "_" and exclude from the results any file extension.
Where `A`, `B` and `C` can be any character or space. I wish to get `AAA`, `BBB` and `CCC`.

I know that `\.(?:.(?!\.))+$` will match `.extension` but I could not combine it with matching "_" for splitting.

Comment: Can't you just replace the extension and split the resulting string on the "_"?

Comment: @JvdV I think that, for whatever reason, the OP is looking for a one liner here which accomplishes both things.

Comment: Exactly, I know that I can do it in two steps but I was 99,9% sure its possible with a one line which I just couldn't figure out. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: What if there is no extension? Do you still want to split `a_b_c` into `['a', 'b', 'c']`?

Comment: space is cheap. readability and maintainability beat brevity.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you wanted to use a regex based approach here, you could try doing a find all on the following regex pattern:

```regex
[^_]+(?=.*\.\w+$)
```

This pattern will match every term in between underscore, *except* for the portion after the extension, which will be excluded by the lookahead.

```cs
Regex rx = new Regex(@"[^_]+(?=.*\.\w+$)");
string text = "AAA_BBB_CCC.extension";
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[0].Value);
}
```

This prints:

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` function to strip the extension from the file name.

Then use `String.Split` to get an array with three items:

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullName);
var parts = fileName.Split('_');
var partAAA = parts[0];
var partBBB = parts[1];
var partCCC = parts[2];
```

If the parts are always the same fixed number of characters long, you can as well extract them using the `Substring` function. No need to resort to regex here.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make use of the .NET [Group.Captures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=net-5.0) property and capture any char except an `_` in a named capture group, which you can extract from the match using a named group.

```
^(?'val'[^_]+)(?:_(?'val'[^_]+))+\.\w+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?'val'[^_]+)` Named group `val`, match 1+ chars other than `_` using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `(?:` Non caputure group

  - `_(?'val'[^_]+)` Match an `_` and capture again 1+ chars other than `_` in same named group `val`
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times for at least 1 occurrence with `_`
- `\.\w+` Match a `.` and 1+ word chars
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%27val%27%5b%5e_%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3a_%28%3f%27val%27%5b%5e_%5d%2b%29%29%2b%5c.%5cw%2b%24&i=AAA_BBB_CCC.extension)

```
string pattern = @"^(?'val'[^_]+)(?:_(?'val'[^_]+))+\.\w+$";
string input = @"AAA_BBB_CCC.extension";            
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
foreach (Capture capture in m.Groups["val"].Captures) {
   Console.WriteLine(capture.Value);
}
```

Output

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

[image]

Comment: The pattern can be shortened to `((?<val>[^_]+)_?)+\..+` and returns the same. And handles a single non `_` such as `AAA.ext`.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan  You could also use that indeed. I used an example with 2 groups to not match `AAA_BBB_CCC_.extension` To also match AAA.txt the quantifier in the current pattern `+` can be changed to `*`